# How are *custom* events in JavaScript actually implemented?

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, dom-events

As far as I understand, events are not part of EcmaScript language,
but of the DOM specification and DOM implementations in the various
engines. From reading about the DOM, I got the impression that the
events are build-in to the engines and you can't have custom ones. On
the other hand, frameworks like jQuery give functions that define
custom events. Similarly you can have custom events in server-side
JavaScript frameworks like Node.js.

I tried to do some research about that and the only conclusion I could
come up with is that the "custom" events are actually abstractions
over true (built-in) events, that the frameworks handle in hidden
parts of the DOM, that are created for that specific purpose.

Is that correct? If not, how are user-defined events actually
implemented in JavaScript?

Comment: This could be interesting: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/

Comment: You're guesses are basically correct. It's either something provided for directly by the runtime system (node.js, modern DOMs), or else it's done in a layer of JavaScript on top of that (libraries like jQuery or Prototype).

Answer (score 3):

The DOM events specification ([v2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/), [v3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/)) provides a means of creating and dispatching events, via methods such as [`createEvent`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-DocumentEvent-createEvent) and [`dispatchEvent`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget-dispatchEvent). It's a DOM thing, not a JavaScript thing. (JavaScript's various features around functions — their being [closures](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html), being first-class objects, etc. — make it really easy to implement events via an observer-style pattern, but that's a different topic.)

Comment: Hi TJ, do you have a link on how I can "implement events via an observer-style pattern"?

Comment: @Kay: You mean for non-DOM stuff?